Biased moderation?
community!
I've been successfully using StackExchange platform for years: helping and being helped. Below you will find the data about my reputation.
Recently I stack with the task of calculating probabilities of winning based on GLICKO1 and GLICKO2 ratings. Understanding the computation of the ratings based on these systems is not a trivial task at all, especially for people who does not have a degree in statistics, and probability computation is more complicated task as it is poorly addressed in sources I was able to find.
In search for help I came here. And what did I got? All 3 my questions were closed! One of them contained even relevant code I was able to find in one of the libraries - to demonstrate, that I really did my studies before I came here.
I wonder, what am I doing wrong - and I cant find an answer. I know how community works - my reputation screams about it. So I wonder, maybe a moderation here is just a little bit too severe? Might that be, that people who came here for help should not be expelled? Or at least they deserve clear comments on what is really wrong with the question and how exactly question should be fixed?
What is the point of this community? - To keep only ideal (by what means?) questions, or to provide help to each other?


Per the only visible closed question you asked, it probably lacked enough details to be answerable. You can still edit it to provide details and make it a candidate to reopening. Generally speaking, there could be disagreement between reviewers, so even experienced users might find that some decisions are too severe or too lax. Moreover, errors can happen, as well as grey areas where reasonable people sharing the same principles can disagree. Consensus may evolve too, e.g. I doubt that a question like this one would be accepted nowadays.

Your question raises many issues on different levels, most of which have been addressed thoughtfully in detailed answers. I will add two simple points here. It's unfortunately common that a question appears too poor to be acceptable without being able to say what the question really is or should be. Two limiting cases are Why doesn't my code work? How should I analyse my data? which are both approximated all too often. Also, your experience with SE should underline an important negative: SE doesn't provide a series of helplines whereby every question should be answered.

Your question here might receive down votes, but note that voting on meta is often subjective like agree/disagree instead of useful/unuseful. So the downvotes might be more directly about your question, "biased or not biased" and not about the fact whether your question is useful or not. I find it correct that you seek advice on meta about your question.

About the title of this thread, I don't think there is such a thing as an unbiased moderation as it's always reflective of an editorial policy. If it's about questioning the policies and their interpretation, it may be healthy to have this kind of conversation from time to time. But it might be hard to get anywhere without being a long-standing member if it's about questioning long ingrained policies. And even so it may still be difficult. While I do not necessarily agree with your point of view about your specific case, I appreciate your question and find it very relevant to ask it on meta.

So that people can understand what you are referring to, I have undeleted the most recent two closed questions.  (The third, from 2014, is not going to provide useful information about current moderation.)  BTW, the Community bot had automatically deleted these posts.

@whuber  the bot deleted them again ...

I read many questions and I'd argue there's no evidence of bias but there's evidence of variability in how the guidelines are applied. This is the perhaps inevitable consequence of three factors: (a) the moderation rules need to be interpreted in order to be applied; (b) different users with voting privileges have different interpretations; (c) not all questions are moderated by all voters. This results in (high?) variance, not bias. Also, writing several similar questions in quick succession rather taking time to consider and improve in response to comments doesn't seem a productive strategy.

@dipetkov You're clearly correct that people with enough reputation to vote to close (and those that ever do that, a much smaller subset) don't always agree about particular threads. There can't be anything different without abolishing the scope for closure OR making every decision need a town meeting. The safeguards as you know are that it needs 3 non-moderators to close a thread and what looks like a bad decision can always be reversed. Most importantly, a vote to close is NOT a vote to delete a thread, nor does it imply that someone is unwelcome in, or to be expelled from, CV!

@NickCox Yes the OP did choose some strong words like "expel", perhaps in a moment of frustration. I've had moments of frustration on SE so I get it. Giving it a bit of time helped me to not see what had occurred in stark terms, hence my advice to the OP not to rush into writing followup questions in response to a closure.

@dipetkov Indeed. Full disclosure: I downvoted this mostly because the phrasing remains intemperate and what is said far exceeds what the evidence substantiates. A downvote doesn't mean that I want to deny anyone's right to discuss closure decisions on Meta.

(-1) Challenging a decision here is fine, but the allegations in the title (bias) and the body (expelled - really?) are entirely unmerited based on such flimsy grounds. Especially because you have experience with Stackexchange, you ought to know how this system works. We're all volunteers here and I don't believe that anybody who gets their question closed 'deserves' an explanation beyond the boilerplate reason chosen.

@NickCox About "a vote to close is NOT a vote to delete a thread": Even if it's not the intention of close voters to have the question deleted, a closed question is automatically deleted after a few days by the community bot, if the question has a score of 0 or less. I initially didn't know that, and learning about it made me a bit more generous with my upvotes for closed questions I find salvageable.

@J-J-J Indeed. At the same time, if a poster failed to revise a question satisfactorily within a few days, sorry, but it doesn't belong. Surprisingly often, such people get a lot of attention from the community, including detailed comments, but then just walk away.  They may walk away feeling demoralized or angry, or they may walk away appreciating that their question was off-topic or too vague, but no one has an absolute right to an answer.

@NickCox Agreed on the idea that no one has an absolute right to an answer. However some closed questions may benefit a wider audience than just the original poster, even if they are never edited and improved for them to be reopened. A closed question may still be useful to other people with similar questions, e.g. to see what kind of details were lacking from the closed question, or other problems or useful considerations raised in the comment section.

Happy to agree that bad questions are instructive on what is a bad question, but SE policy is that such questions are doomed. I sometimes think that sample bad and good questions  might feature in the Help Center if indeed they are not there already, but would that be read? How much help do people deserve? I routinely see questions that are close to Why doesn't my code work? How should I analyse my data? How to interpret my results? What techniques should I use for ...? with little or no detail. I don't have the inclination to explain at length that these are just not good questions.

The best way to be nice on SE is give a good answer to a good question.

Your failure to visit this thread (during a time when you have interacted with our main site) calls into question the motivation behind your post.  Are you just ranting, or are you interested in engaging with the community to improve the site?  And, in trying to understand better where you are coming from, I wonder what is it about your reputation that "screams"?  Would it be the single post (out of five total) with a positive number of votes, or something else?

I am not able to check the two questions out of your three that have been closed, as per your statement. But this one's closure was justifiable in that the question was vague and unclear to be answerable. As Sycorax pointed out:

... you don't state which part of the computation is giving you trouble.

Merely stating one is having problem with some computation is typically not a detailed question to be answerable. You can edit it and provide necessary details as to what exactly bugged you, where you got stuck.

One of them contained even relevant code I was able to find in one of the libraries - to demonstrate, that I really did my studies before I came here.

Without seeing the whole post, I will not be able to conclude why the post was closed. But perhaps you might not be aware about the scope of this community. Simply stating some code snippet doesn't guarantee the question is even on-topic or having enough details for a comprehensive answer.

I wonder, maybe a moderation here is just a little bit too severe? Might that be, that people who came here for help should not be expelled?

Trust me, the moderation is way more liberal as compared with CV's other cousins. It takes three different reviewers (non-mod) to vote to close a question. If the user edits providing whatever is sought, then it gets reopened, again due to the collective of three different users. Sometimes mods single-handedly reopen posts that they feel were erroneously closed. So yes, errors do happen. But for all intents and purposes, you can be assured that there would be enough vigilance from the mods and other users of the community to amend such actions.
And no one is expelled here. That is a bit of overwrought reaction. A  question will closed based on the content of the post, irrespective of who the user is, what their rep scores are here or at other SE communities.

What is the point of this community? - To keep only ideal (by what means?) questions, or to provide help to each other?

The point of this community is to create and maintain a repository of quality statistical contents in the form of comprehensive questions and answers. Questions ranging from elementary probability theory to advanced theoretical concepts can be found here. And this is obviously not antithetical to providing help!
At the end of the day, what determines whether a question gets answers  and not get closed is what useable information the user has provided.

I would not have closed your question, but I do see why others could have done it.
There could be multiple issues.

You are asking for a simple fact that is easily available if you read the manual. These rating systems often compute some expected score (and without draws that is equal to win probability) and the formulas are available for it.
So when you ask for such a fact people will wonder what the problem is... since the answer seems like a simple citation from the manual or a Wikipedia page, so what is the point of asking? Why do you not understand the formulas? What do you exactly need to have explained.
Yes, this is biased (considering it to be trivial while it might not be trivial to you), but for good reasons. Your question was very short and it is difficult to understand where you are going and what you are missing or not understanding about the description of the rating system. The goal of StackExchange is not to just replicate/quote Wikipedia articles, it is about answering questions with new content and descriptions. If you explain in your question more in detail what you did and understand, then the question becomes more different from asking a citation from the manual or Wikipedia and a better, more suitable, answer can be provided.

Your question is phrased poorly. You are using brief dense language and asking for

Given ... mu, phi and sigma for GLICO1 or GLICO2 systems

which is very dense with specific terms that might be unknown to many. You do give a reference to glicko rating systems, but you should at least as well introduce mu, phi and sigma. You cannot just use such abbreviations and expect other people to understand them.
On this platform it might be reasonable to speak about mu and sigma when speaking about mean and standard deviation (since those Greek letters are standard notations for these terms in statistics) and also if context allows the reader to understand you speak about these standards. But in your case the context is not clear and it may also not be a standard use (and if it is the standard use, and it refers to the mean and standard deviation, then it is still unclear what mean and deviation it relates to).


